# What is the leading theory on the origin of the red hair gene?

Tags: untagged

The red hair gene; does it come from the Vikings, or the British celts (primarily the Gaelic celts therein)?

The main argument for the ginger gene originating in Scandinavia that I've heard, is that the map of ginger hair concentrations aligns nicely with Viking trade routes ([Rouă, 2016](https://www.thedockyards.com/red-hair/)). Another detail to consider is that Thor, of Norse mythology, has been described with red hair/beard ([Davidson, 1977](https://books.google.no/books?id=8RYSAQAAIAAJ&q=%22Thorhall%20boasted%20to%20his%20Christian%20companions%20:%20Redbeard%20has%20got%20the%20better%20of%20your%20Christ%20!%22%22&dq=%22Thorhall%20boasted%20to%20his%20Christian%20companions%20:%20Redbeard%20has%20got%20the%20better%20of%20your%20Christ%20!%22%22&hl=en&ei=ppm5TYL3F5P0swOWm_XlBw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&sqi=2&redir_esc=y)). Thor predates the Viking age, so this can't be explained by pre-Viking age Norsemen observing ginger-haired people in the British Isles.

I have a few counter-arguments against the red-haired Thor argument:

1. Thor only gained the description as red-haired after Viking invasions into the British isles.
2. The "inventors" of Thor had somehow seen red-haired people before the Viking age.
3. The red hair wasn't inspired by a real human trait, but was rather an imagined trait, which is okay given Thor isn't human.

The first counter can potentially be verified by diving into the historic accounts of Thor, and seeing when red-haired descriptions became popular. The cited book by Davidson draws from the Icelandic sagas, who were written by Christians, not Norse pagans. If 1. is correct, then either Thor went through changes in his descriptions within the actual mythology after the Vikings laid eyes on the insular celts, or, the red-hair was imparted onto him by Christian Icelanders. Apparently, the Eddas make no mention of a red-haired or -bearded Thor; these descriptions begin in the Sagas ([Seigfried, 2011](https://www.norsemyth.org/2011/09/blond-thor-stan-lee-wasnt-wrong.html)). Perhaps the Christians decided to make Thor red-haired/bearded as a symbol of his demonic nature ([Kaplan, 2008](https://www.jstor.org/stable/20722663)), mirroring that of the Devilish Viking scourge that harrowed their ancestors?

The second counter is interesting, because it not only counters the theory of the ginger gene originating in Scandinavia, it also counters the theory of the ginger gene originating with the insular celts. I think it is very improbable the Thor is red-haired in Norse mythology because insular celts described Thor as such. The Norse mythology did not come from the mythology of the insular celts. Alternatively, I don't think a red-haired Thor could have arisen as a insular celtic version of Thor, that was then brought to Scandinavia, where it replaced the previous version of Thor, since AFAIK, there weren't any mass emigration of insular celts to Scandinavia during that time.

If we're assuming that 2. is correct, we have thus two plausible possibilities:

Either, Norse people saw red-haired people before/around the time of Thor's creation.

Or, Thor already had red hair when he arrived into Norse mythology.

Both of these imply the presence of red-haired people in continental Europe. My mind goes to the Gauls. The name of Thor has been linguistically traced back to the Gauls ([Matasović, 2009](https://books.google.no/books?id=YN_YPQAACAAJ&redir_esc=y)) ([Koch, 2020](https://www.wales.ac.uk/Resources/Documents/Centre/2020/Celto-Germanic2020.pdf)), though its history goes further back than that. This means that before Thor made its way into Norse mythology, it passed through the Gallic people, which is perhaps where he gained his red-hair. Alternatively, with a red-haired Gallic people, there would be red-haired people for the Norsemen to observe and potentially breed with, thus gaining a red-haired subpopulation themselves. With the knowledge of humans with red hair, it is then more likely that one of their gods would wind up with red hair.

If the Gauls were red-haired, it explains why the Gaelic people are so often red-haired, and it could explain why Thor is red-haired. If there, for some reason, was extensive interbreeding between the Norse and Gallic peoples, then this could explain the alignment of the maps of Viking trade routes and ginger hair concentrations. The hypothesis of a Gallic origin of the ginger gene would have to account for why there isn't such a high concentration of red-hair there now though. Perhaps war and famine disproportionally affecting Gaul during some period, followed by other ethnicities migrating into the vacant lands, could explain this?

So, what is the leading theory nowadays? Is the origin of the ginger gene most likely Gaelic, Norse or Gallic?

Comment: ["Estimates on the original occurrence of the currently active gene for red hair vary from 20,000 to 100,000 years ago".](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_hair#Evolution) That's quite a while before the Norsemen.

Comment: @LarsBosteen Yes, never heard of this discovery. If this evidence trumphs that of the other theories, then perhaps the answer to my last question is "none of them, it originates from x"?

Comment: The Gauls were Celts, not Gaulish.

Comment: @Jos Ah, I've mixed up the adjectival form of Gaul and the word for the Gallic language, *Gaulish*. I've corrected it, now using *Gallic* where *Gaulish* once stood.

Comment: Red hair is not uncommon throughout Asia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_hair#Asia_(all_regions)  and predates the Vikings https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherchen_Man

Comment: Dang. Was digging through genomes looking at another (now closed) question the other day, and came over some material about this. All those tabs are gone now though. But there 100% are historical records of red-haired Celts during the height of their culture.

Answer (score 7):

The question as currently posed isn't directly answerable because it is based on overly simplistic assumptions about how genetics work.

The presence of red hair doesn't always indicate the presence of a specific gene or vice versa. [About 80%](https://www.nature.com/articles/ng1195-328) of people with red hair have a variant of [MC1R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melanocortin_1_receptor), the so-called "ginger gene". This gene is much older than humans and regulates pigmentation in a wide range of other mammals. It is also important to understand that there are [many variants](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022202X15401411) of this gene which may or may not be associated with red hair.

At the level of [haplogroups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haplogroup) and [subclades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subclade) rather than any particular gene, we can infer [complex patterns of population mixture in Europe over recent centuries](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4714572/). Here's an interesting map of how haplogroups are thought to have moved through Europe over time:

[image: map]

In sum **"the ginger gene" definitely did not *originate* in the Celtic or Nordic region** and then move from one to the other. Specific variations of it inhereted from Germanic populations may have become more prevelant over time, but if so, this would have happened indepently in each of the two areas.

Comment: The thing I like the most about this answer is calling out that genetics don't quite work that way. My favorite example of this is the sickle-cell gene, maps of which are practically a scatterplot of historical malaria distribution. It does NOT plot migrations of cultures or peoples, just where that genetic trait is helpful. Red hair is genetically tied with low melanin levels (at least one way to get there), which is more healthy in northern latitudes, and more unhealthy in lower latitudes.

Comment: I didn't address that directly in my answer but yes, variations of MC1R do relate to melanin and it does seem that the prevelance of red hair and adaptation to northern latitudes are at least loosely connected.